# Modal that blocks specific element on page

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm using Bootstrap 4. From Bootstrap's `Modal` [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal):

> They’re positioned over everything else in the document and remove
>   scroll from the  so that modal content scrolls instead.

Suppose we need to show a block of content which overlays a specific HTML element only, not the whole page. For example, assume we have a header, menu and tab set on the page. We want a modal which blocks the tab content area only, not the header, menu and ability to switch tabs.

Is it possible to implement this with Bootstrap and how do you do it?

Comment: The real question is, why would one ever wants that? Of course it is doable, but you'll have to code it by yourself.

Comment: @RacilHilan: To answer your `why?` question, I've provided the real-world use case for this in my question. As for the second part of your comment, do you mean it should be coded completely from scratch and BS doesn't provide any building blocks like overlay, modal container with positioning control, scroll bars management, etc. which we could use (or adapt) for this case?

Comment: Yes, you provided an example, by my point was that the example doesn't make sense. Why would one ever want to overlay a *a specific HTML element only*? The purpose of the modal dialog is to prevent the user from interacting with anything else on the page, and the purpose of the overlay in that case is to provide a visual effect that conveys that meaning. Hence, overlaying one part of the page makes no sense. You can simply disable or hide that part if you like. You can position the modal and overlay as you wish, but you will need to do the calculation by yourself.

Comment: @RacilHilan: Again, your question `why?` is already answered in my post: `We want a modal which blocks the tab content area only, not the header, menu and ability to switch tabs`. If your modal relates to just a part of the page, there is no need to block everything, especially if user should have the ability to interact with the parts of your page independently of each other. Not sure why you believe it doesn't make sense. Conversely, it seems that limiting the idea of modals to block the whole page only does not make sense.

Comment: I explained why it doesn't make sense. You need to understand what modal dialog means. In any software (not only BS or websites), modal dialogs block interaction with anything else in the software. That's what they're designed for and that's what their name "modal" means. If you want to only block part of the page, that's fine, but it's not called modal. Did you read what BS defines modal to be: *They’re positioned over everything else in the document and remove scroll from the body so that modal content scrolls instead*.

Comment: From the UI perspective, you are right that modals are not always the best choice. They are usually an easy (and lazy) way to block everything until the user selects something. However, your example is not any less lazy. You want to block the tab, but the user can use the menu to go to another page bypassing the modal. This can be implemented by providing a proper cancel/close button on the modal. Anyway, instead of trying to modify the modal, simply provide a non-modal dialog and disable the tab. you can also change the CSS `opaque` of the tab to mimic an overlay.

Comment: @RacilHilan: I think you should refrain from using the dogma "modal must block everything". It's great point for abstract discussions, but in the real world, you could have been seen plethora of apps with modals blocking part of the app. And in the first place, I believe the proper place for this kind of discussions is StackExchange [UX community](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gui-design). This question is not about the best UI practices, but about the specific problem and ways to solve it with Bootstrap.

Comment: A Modal is a very specific construct with a well defined, expected usage across all platforms both web based and desktop apps.  I think you may be better served by [Bootstrap's Popover](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#popovers)

Comment: It's not my dogma and I'm not creating it. Modals probably existed before I was born. Read it [here on Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/) (the first bullet which I copied in my previous comment). And, no, I've never seen a modal that blocks part of the app. By definition, that cannot be a modal. Here is a general [definition on StackExchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/12046).

Comment: @fnostro: Popover seems to solve a quite different task, since it doesn't contain an overlay blocking underlying content. it needs certain visual and API tweaks. Could you expand on what is the technical difference between a current implementation of modal blocking the `body` element and a modal blocking any random `div` element on the page?

Comment: @RacilHilan: As I said, general definitions are great for abstract discussions. Try to find a reference explicitly proving `if a component blocks part of app only, but otherwise behaves exactly like a modal, then it could not be considered a modal`. I would be very zealous to learn from that reasoning, hopefully, it would be based on some real-world qualities, not on, I'm sorry again, dogmas.

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov: true, but if you are going to have to customize something to make it suit your needs, personally, I wouldn't modify the functionality of a well-known concept.  maybe look into a third part utility like [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)

Comment: @fnostro: Thank you for this, I'll check it out! The misunderstanding here is that I'm not modifying the concept of modals. Imagine you develop a VM management app and every VM screen is displayed in its own tab. When the manager app wants to prompt a user for something specific and blocking to a certain VM only, it doesn't want to block its whole window, so the user is unable to do anything to other VMs, right? But that blocking prompt still is a modal. The only difference with usual understanding is that it blocks one tab only.

Comment: Hahaha, that's hilarious. How can I find that? You're probably the only person in the world who thinks that way :). Definitions are not for abstract discussions. They are the base of standards. How does it behave like a modal if it only blocks part of the app? The only behaviour of a modal is blocking the entire app, so in what other way does your idea behave like a modal? There is no other behaviour. Do you notice that you're disagreeing with everybody? You cannot create definitions by yourself. A modal is a modal, it blocks the entire app. Period. You're examples are not modals.

Comment: @RacilHilan: Right, if you can't find a reference disproving other person's point, then there is no reason forcing your point on others. And no, you're not quite close to the truth saying I'm the only person thinking this way.

Comment: You need to learn how to understand what others say. How is it my point? I didn't create modals or their definition. Why don't you find any reference that says that a modals can block part of the app? My little son has a duck toy that swims and does everything like a duck. Do you consider it a duck? Don't force your point, go find a reference that says it's not considered a duck. This discussion is pointless. Contact BS and tell them that their modal makes no sense, like you said in your comment. Then teach them how modals should bock part of the page. They will fix the modal for you.

Comment: It was you who started this discussion and who was unable to go by the question when OP asked for help with using stuff in the way you believe wrong. I think you need to learn how to stop trying to teach others abstract stuff when they actually ask concrete practical questions.